# How do I use core.match in Clojurescript with goog.events.KeyCodes?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.match

```
(defn editing-mode? []
  "a hardcoded (for the moment) value, will look up in db later"
  false)

(def UP 38) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.UP
(def DOWN 40) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.DOWN
(def LEFT 37) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.LEFT
(def RIGHT 39) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.RIGHT
(def W 87) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.W
(def S 83) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.S
(def A 65) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.A
(def D 68) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.D
(def E 69) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.E
(def ESC 27) ;; goog.events.KeyCodes.ESC

(defn delta [e]
  ;; e is a google closure Event
  (js/console.log (.-keyCode e))
  (js/console.log (editing-mode?))
  (match [(editing-mode?) (.-keyCode e)]
   [false 38] [:slide :up]
   [false 40] [:slide :down]
   [false 37] [:slide :left]
   [false 39] [:slide :right]
   [false 87] [:slide :up]
   [false 83] [:slide :down]
   [false 65] [:slide :left]
   [false 68] [:slide :right]
   [false 69] [:start-editing]
   [true 27]  [:done-editing]
   :else nil))
```

The above code works. However, If I try to be a little less wordy and use the goog keycodes directly, like so

```
(match [(editing-mode?) (.-keyCode e)]
  [false goog.events.KeyCodes.UP] [:slide :up]
  [false goog.events.keyCodes.DOWN] [:slide :down]
  ...
```

I get the following cljsbuild error:

```
...
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Invalid local name: goog.events.KeyCodes.UP ...
...
```

Ok, so I can't use the `goog.events.KeyCodes.*` themselves, but maybe I can use a `def` referenced to them? So I try

```
(match [(editing-mode?) (.-keyCode e)]
   [false UP] [:slide :up]
   [false DOWN] [:slide :down]
   ...
```

This does compile, but now match just isn't working. Every key event matches to the `[false UP]` match clause (core.match always emits `[:slide :up]`).

Anyway, the first code example does work. But why can't I use `goog.events.KeyCodes.*` or references to `goog.events.KeyCodes.*` in my core.match matcher? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key part of `core.match` is that symbols will be bound to values rather than being matched against. That is, the current value of `UP` *is not* looked up and used in the match; instead, the symbol `UP` gets bound to the value `(.-keyCode e)` when `false` gets matched.

Unfortunately, insofar as I know, there's nothing you can do about that with `core.match`. It's very much dependent on literal values. However, since your pattern is fairly simple, you could use `(conp = ...)`.

Comment: Note that you can match against locals, so one workaround would be to first `(let [...]` your keycodes and then match against that local binding: https://github.com/clojure/core.match/blob/5d08fcf3faa1f36917e152591219c0baf03868c4/src/test/cljs/core/match/tests.cljs#L390-L418

Answer (score 1):

You can only match [against local bindings](https://github.com/clojure/core.match/blob/5d08fcf3faa1f36917e152591219c0baf03868c4/src/test/cljs/core/match/tests.cljs#L390-L418):

```
      (= (let [x 2
               y 2]
           (match [x]
             [0] :a0
             [1] :a1
             [y] :a2
             :else :a3))
        :a2))
```

So you could achieve your result with first binding the keycodes to a local variables via `(let [...])`.

Answer (score 1):

I like to construct a map of "keyname" to "keycode" by simply inverting the KeyCodes object:

```
(ns awesome.sauce
  (:require [clojure.set :as set])
  (:import [goog.events KeyCodes]))

(def codename
  (set/map-invert (js->clj KeyCodes)))
```

Then I can identify keys with strings instead of clunky interop (and strings are values so play nicely with matching):

```
(match [(editing-mode?) (codename (.-keyCode e))]
   [false "UP"] [:slide :up]
   [false "DOWN"] [:slide :down])
```